# Function for inserting a value in binary tree?

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I have a function **insert** that is used to insert values into the Binary tree.
But when I log out the **value** nothing is shown.

I'm aware of the insertion using **member function**.

The root node's value is not being updated?

Could someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node{

 public:
     int value;
     Node* left;
     Node* right;

     Node();

     Node(int data){
     value = data;
     left = NULL;
     right = NULL; 
    } 


};

void insert(Node* root , int val){
     if(root == NULL){
         root = new Node(val);
         return;
     }
    if(root->value > val)
         insert(root->left,val);
     else
        insert(root->right,val);


} 

int main()
   class Node* root  = NULL;
   insert(root,5);
   cout<<root->value;
 }
```

Comment: You pass `Node* root` to `insert()` i.e. the pointer by value. Hence, changes to `root` get lost if you return from `insert()`. Change it to `Node*& root` to pass it by reference and achieve that the "original" pointer is changed (instead of a local copy).

Comment: FYI: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/7478597) In a debugger, you should have seen that the modified `root` is lost once you return from `insert()`. Debugging is an essential technique concerning software development.

Comment: I, tried debugging and noticed that root was 0x00 the whole time. I couldn't make out something was wrong but didn't know how to approach it.

Comment: Yeah, I was aware that the debugger could have shown the problem but, of course, doesn't offer the solution... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are inserting position on the right place but the problem is you are not creating the `link` of your newly inserted node to it's parent.

you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44565542/8359623) as reference!